# Error: _reactNativeRouterFlux.Actions.TimeInput is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

`react-native-router-flux` works for all of the scenes in my app apart from `TimeInput`. I'm triggering the action though an on press handler.

Why is it not working?

Action:

```js
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      contact: {},
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const contact = await retrieveAddressBook();
      this.setState({ loading: false, contact: contact })
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert(error.detail[0]);
    }
  }

  handleOnClick = () => {
    Actions.TimeInput();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <>
          <Loader />
        </>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>
            {this.state.contact[0].name}
          </Text>
          <Text onPress={this.handleOnClick}>
            {this.state.contact[0].phone}
          </Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Router

```js
import TimeInput from '../components/TimeInput'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StoreProvider store={store}>
        <PaperProvider>
          <Router>
            <Scene key='root'>
              <Scene
                key='RootContainer'
                component={RootContainer}
                title='RootContainer'
                hideNavBar={true}
                initial
                />
              <Scene
                key='PhoneNumberInput'
                component={PhoneNumberInput}
                title='PhoneNumberInput'
                hideNavBar={true}
                />
              <Scene
                key='SmsCodeInput'
                component={SmsCodeInput}
                title='SmsCodeInput'
                hideNavBar={true}
                />
              <Scene
                key='Dashboard'
                component={Dashboard}
                title='Dashboard'
                hideNavBar={true}
              />
              <Scene
                key='TimeInput'
                component={TimeInput}
                title='TimeInput'
                hideNavBar={true}
              />
            </Scene>
          </Router>
        </PaperProvider>
      </StoreProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default (App);
```

TimeInput component

```
import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker'

class TimeInput extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <>
      <DateTimePicker /> 
    </>
    )
  }
}

export default TimeInput;
```

Comment: `TimeInput` is your own custom component, but you're trying to call it as if it's a member of `'react-native-router-flux'.Actions`.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG, why then does this method work for everyone one of my other custom components? For example `Actions.Dashboard();`

Comment: Oh, I didn't see 'TimeInput' class. This is a prop.